# how to add an xml file to the java application's classpath in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, classpath

I need an xml file to be accessed via the classpath in a java application i am creating . how to achieve it in eclipse

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd generate a separate resources folder, right-click it and select `Build Path > Use as Source Folder`. That way it's on the class path, but you're not mixing it with your Java source files

Answer (score 1):

Put the directory *containing* the XML in the runtime classpath, then use `className.Class.getResourceAsStream()` to get an InputStream containing the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in java source folder, and use it as resource