# Java: Run Program without Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a game that uses external libraries and resource files. Now I want test it on another PC(with Ubuntu OS), I tried to run it without eclipse by exporting to jar files, but it doesn't work. This is the hierarchy. Is there any simple way to do this ?

[image]

**Edit**
When I export it as Runnable(**Note that I'm trying to run it still on windows not ubuntu**) jar file and try to run it `java -jar gra.jar` It throws:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)

        at MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:14)
        ... 5 more`
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with 'java -jar <jarname.jar>' - what happens?

Comment: At first time I used another options to export and it threw exception. And now I get `no main manifest attribute, in game.jar`. I'll try again export to show this exception.

Comment: Have you tried putting the native files in the same directory as the jar file?

Comment: @Oskar Well, after few attempts I tried this and It worked, I guess It's the simplest way:P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are [getting your resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file) correctly, not referencing them in your local file system.

To ensure your resources are put in the JAR [add them to your classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832064/how-to-add-an-xml-file-to-the-java-applications-classpath-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path`

`lwjgl` is not found. It should be in one of the directories listed in `java.library.path`.

You most certainly added a directory to `java.library.path` with the native dlls of `jwgl` when you set up your project. Eclipse cannot export this. You will have to create a starter script (sh, bat) which adds the dlls.

Have a look at the last step here:
http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse

Comment: I'm confused a little, because this link has info about setting up whole project what I did. And last step has also  been done in my case.

Comment: Yes you did that right. However, if you do export as a jar, eclipse can't add the dlls to the java.library.path for you. You have to do that yourself. E.g.: `java -Djava.library.path=my/dll/folder -jar my.jar`. You could also use `System.loadLibrary()` and put the dlls in your jar.

Answer (score 0):

How did you pack the jar? If you used solely eclipse, you should use jarsplice. That may fix the error